# How to include an And() Expression that checks for a Property and it's value

Tags: entity-framework, lambda, expression, expression-trees

I'd like to add a check in our repository that filters all objects out on a companyId if it's there and if it matches a given value.

So where we have:

```
public T First<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T : EntityObject  
{  
   var set = GetObjectSet<T>();  
   return set.FirstOrDefault<T>();  
}
```

I would like to add line which looks something where...

```
express.And("Check for CompanyId property if it exists then make sure it = 3");
```

Any ideas on how to go about this?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a function which you can use to tack on a company id check to your expression if a company id exists on the entity, this should do the trick:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CheckPropertyIfExists<T, TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, string propertyName, TProperty propertyValue)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName, typeof(TProperty));
    if(property == null || !property.CanRead)
        return expression;

    return expression.Update(
        Expression.And( // && 
            Expression.Equal( // ==
                Expression.MakeMemberAccess(expression.Parameters[0], property), // T parameter.{propertyName}
                Expression.Constant(propertyValue) // specified propertyValue constant
            ),
            expression.Body // Original expression
        ),
        expression.Parameters
    );
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
public T First<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, int companyId)
{
    var set = GetObjectSet<T>();  
    return set.FirstOrDefault<T>(CheckPropertyIfExists(expression, "CompanyId", companyId));  
}
```

And now you can call your `First` method with your expression and the companyId you want to filter by.

A slightly better way to do this might be to use it as a filtering method, i.e. rewrite it as an extension method that doesn't require an inner expression and works on an object query (or IQueryable):

```
public static ObjectQuery<T> FilterByPropertyIfExists<T, TProperty>(this ObjectQuery<T> query, string propertyName, TProperty propertyValue)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName, typeof(TProperty));
    if(property == null || !property.CanRead)
        return query;

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Equal( // ==
            Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property), // T parameter.{propertyName}
            Expression.Constant(propertyValue) // specified propertyValue constant
        ),
        parameter
    );
    return query.Where(predicate);
}
```

The beauty of this is that it will work really nicely with the stanard LINQ syntaxes (both query and fluent).

e.g. it allows queries like this:

```
from x in repository.Clients.FilterByPropertyIfExists("Company", 5)
where x == ???
select x.Name;
```

**[EDIT]**

I've cleaned it up a bit and added a check on parameter visibility (must be a public, static property), as well as an ObjectQuery implementation (which will be automatically used for ObjectQuery and ObjectSet):

```
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> FilterByPropertyIfExists<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> query, string propertyName, TProperty propertyValue)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        var property = type.GetProperty(
            propertyName, 
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, // Must be a public instance property
            null, 
            typeof(TProperty), // Must be of the correct return type
            Type.EmptyTypes, // Can't have parameters
            null
        );
        if (property == null || !property.CanRead) // Must exist and be readable
            return query; // Return query unchanged

        // Create a predicate to pass to the Where method
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "it");
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Equal( // ==
                Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property), // T parameter.{propertyName}
                Expression.Constant(propertyValue) // specified propertyValue constant
            ),
            parameter
        );
        return query.Where(predicate); // Filter the query
    }

    public static ObjectQuery<T> FilterByPropertyIfExists<T, TProperty>(this ObjectQuery<T> query, string propertyName, TProperty propertyValue)
    {
        var filteredQuery = FilterByPropertyIfExists((IQueryable<T>)query, propertyName, propertyValue);
        return (ObjectQuery<T>)filteredQuery; // Cast filtered query back to an ObjectQuery
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that looks interesting! Do you think it will also work with LINQ to Entities? For instance: Using your `CheckPropertyIfExists` as a predicate on `FirstOrDefault`, would this work in LINQ to Entities? (My understanding was that the predicate must be translatable to SQL statements and that I can only use "canonical functions" inside of the predicate, but I am not quite sure how all this goes in detail.)

Comment: Yeah, it I've tested it and it works with LINQ to Entities. It should work with LINQ to SQL too. It's still translatable to SQL statements because it doesn't introduce anything doesn't appear in any simple where clause. It's still bound by the same rules as L2E though, i.e. it won't work with an `enum` value.

Comment: Great! I'll play around with this when I have a bit time. I didn't know that the `Expression` class offers such a lot and powerful features.

Comment: Yeah, expression trees are really great, but they're a bit tough to get your head around at first. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a good candidate for an interface to stay away from reflection:

```
public interface ICompanyFilterable
{
  int CompanyId { get; set; }
}

public partial class YourEntity : ICompanyFilterable
{
    ....
}

public static IQueryable<T> FilterByCompanyId<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int companyId)
    where T : ICompanyFilterable
{
    return query.Where(e => e.CompanyId == companyId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bennor, 
Thanks so much your posting was VERY useful.

I took what you put in there and created an extension method which appends the 'And' filter to the existing expression.

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AddEqualityCheck<T, TProperty>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, string propertyName, TProperty propertyValue)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        var property = type.GetProperty(
            propertyName,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
            null,
            typeof(TProperty),
            Type.EmptyTypes,
            null
        );

        if (property == null || !property.CanRead)
        {
            return expression;
        }
        else
        {
            var equalityExpression = Expression.Equal(
                Expression.MakeMemberAccess(expression.Parameters[0], property),
                Expression.Constant(propertyValue)
                );
            var andEqualityExpression = Expression.And(equalityExpression, expression.Body);
            return expression.Update(andEqualityExpression, expression.Parameters);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cool, but that's exactly what the first block of code in my answer does ;)